# Backend of my web administration app

Tags: backend

I am developing an Android app in which the admin has to add some content and  retrieve/view the content throw a web administration app . So do I implement the backend of the administration separately from the backend of my a android app ? or i will use the same for both ? 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I do them separately.  It makes for more work, but the Admin API, which generally has more powerful functions, is then completely separate.  You can then throw in some additional protections (VPN, IP whitelisting, ..?) to the Admin API server.

I also tend to make the Admin web site accessible only through a VPN.

Note that this doesn't prevent hacking, at best it makes it a more difficult, but I believe it's worthwhile.